# SwiftUI view not animating when bound to @Published var if action isn't completed immediately

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view that is swapping out certain controls depending on state. I'm trying to use MVVM, so most/all of my logic has been pushed off to a view model. I have found that when doing a complex action that modifies a `@Published var` on the view model, the `View` will not animate.

Here's an example where a 1.0s timer in the view model simulates other work being done before changing the `@Published var` value:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showCircle = true
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            VStack {
                if showCircle {
                    Circle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }

                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.showCircle.toggle()
                    }

                }) {
                    Text("With State Variable")
                }
            }

            VStack {
                if viewModel.showCircle {
                    Circle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                }
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        self.viewModel.toggle()
                    }
                }) {
                    Text("With ViewModel Observation")
                }
            }
        }
    }


    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var showCircle = true

        public func toggle() {
            // Do some amount of work here. The Time is just to simulate work being done that may not complete immediately.
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
                self?.showCircle.toggle()
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the case of view model workflow your `withAnimation` does nothing, because not state is changed during this case (it is just a function call), only timer is scheduled, so you'd rather need it as

```
Button(action: {
    self.viewModel.toggle()  // removed from here
}) {
    Text("With ViewModel Observation")
}

...

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { [weak self] _ in
    withAnimation { // << added here
        self?.showCircle.toggle()
    }
}
```

However I would rather recommend to rethink view design... like

```
VStack {
    if showCircle2 { // same declaration as showCircle
        Circle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
    Button(action: {
        self.viewModel.toggle()
    }) {
        Text("With ViewModel Observation")
    }
    .onReceive(viewModel.$showCircle) { value in
        withAnimation {
            self.showCircle2 = value
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Comment: I am trying to build the view so it reacts nicely in response to changes in the view model. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: @lepolt, see updated. Animation is View's feature, so it is better to keep it in view. See updated part for the case you have view model async property update.

Comment: I did not know about .onReceive... but I think this might work...will test later and report back!

Comment: This is my first complex app using SwiftUI and I think I need to step back and re-think some of the architecture. `.onReceive` works, except I have another problem with a `.sheet` presentation and its binding firing more than once, but that's a topic for another day.

Answer (score 5):

The parent view animates the hiding and the showing of its child views. If you place an `.animation(.easeIn)` (or .easeOut or whatever you like) at the end of your first VStack it should work as expected.

As such...

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var showCircle = true
@ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            if showCircle {
                Circle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }

            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.showCircle.toggle()
                }

            }) {
                Text("With State Variable")
            }
        }

        VStack {
            if viewModel.showCircle {
                Circle().frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.viewModel.toggle()
                }
            }) {
                Text("With ViewModel Observation")
            }
        }
    }.animation(.easeIn)
  }
}
```

Comment: Downside of this approach is that it will apply animations to all children and grand children views. It may solve this particular problem that OP mentioned, but may not be the best solution to follow for other general use cases with complex child views.

Answer (score -2):

You must use delay for Animation instead of using a Timer to delay your animations.

```
Button(action: {
    withAnimation(Animation.linear.delay(1.0)) {
        self.viewModel.showCircle.toggle()
    }
}) {
    Text("With ViewModel Observation")
}
```

Otherwise, changes in your view model will behave just as expected when you are not using a Timer.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showCircle = true

    public func toggle() {

        /* other operations */

        self.showCircle.toggle()
    }

}
```

Comment: The Timer was just to simulate "work going on that might not finish immediately." I'm not guaranteed to know how long that work will take, so adding a 1.0s delay is not a good solution.

Comment: @lepolt In that case your viewmodel will just work fine when the state is not changed inside a Timer. btw, did you downvote?