# SwiftUI: Init ObservableObject based on Environment

Tags: ios, swiftui

In this example, the blue rectangle should be initially visible on devices with `.regular` size class and hidden on devices with `.compact` size class.

I'm using an `ObservableObject` called `Settings` and the `@Published` variable `isVisible` to manage visibilty of the rectangle. My problem is that I don't know how I can init `Settings` with the correct `horizontalSizeClass` from my `ContentView`. Right now I am using `.onAppear` to change the value of `isVisible` but this triggers `.onReceive`. On compact devices this causes the rectangle to be visible and fading out when the view is presented instead of being invisible right away.

How can I init `Settings` based on Environment values like `horizontalSizeClass` so that `isVisible` is correct from the start?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    @StateObject var settings = Settings()
    @State var opacity: CGFloat = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle Visibility") {
                settings.isVisible.toggle()
            }
            .onReceive(settings.$isVisible) { _ in
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2.0)) {
                    opacity = settings.isVisible ? 1 : 0
                }
            }
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .opacity(opacity)
        }
        .onAppear {
            settings.isVisible = horizontalSizeClass == .regular // too late
        }
    }
}

class Settings: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isVisible: Bool = true // can't get size class here
}
```

The rectangle should not be visible on start:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need just perform dependency injection (environment is known is parent so easily can be injected into child), and it is simple to do with internal view, like

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass

    struct MainView: View {
        // later knonw injection
        @EnvironmentObject var settings: Settings

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Button("Toggle Visibility") {
                    settings.isVisible.toggle()
                }
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .opacity(settings.isVisible ? 1 : 0) // << direct dependency !!
            }
            .animation(.linear(duration: 2.0), value: settings.isVisible) // << explicit animation
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        MainView()          // << internal view
            .environmentObject(
                Settings(isVisible: horizontalSizeClass == .regular) // << initial injecttion !!
            )
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image: demo]

[Test code is here](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestEnvironmentDepenencyInjectionIinternalView.swift)

Comment: we shouldn't init objects over and over again in `body` 

Comment: @malhal, we don't, we are root view, obviously.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi, this is exactly what I needed! Another key learning from your answer is to use `.animation` instead of `withAnimation`. I build an indirect opacity dependency with `.onReceive` since using `withAnimation` to change a published var does not properly animate (found this in an older answer of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60618042). Do I understand correctly that this approach with `.onReceive` is outdated by now in general (as @malhal suggests in his answer)?

Comment: No, it is not outdated, it is just for publishers, I mean in general, which are not ObservableObject, in example notifications, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`withAnimation` should be done on the Button action changing the state, e.g.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RectangleTestView: View {

    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) var horizontalSizeClass
    @State var settings = Settings()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle Visibility") {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2.0)) {
                    settings.isVisible.toggle()
                }
            }
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .opacity(settings.opacity)
        }
        .onAppear {
            settings.isVisible = horizontalSizeClass == .regular
        }
    }
}

struct Settings {
    var isVisible: Bool = true
    var opacity: CGFloat {
        isVisible ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

FYI we don't really use `onReceive` anymore since they added `onChange`. Also its best to keep view data in structs not move it to expensive objects. "Views are very cheap, we encourage you to make them your primary encapsulation mechanism" [Data Essentials in SwiftUI WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10040) at 20:50.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my example is a simplification from a much more complex app and I need an `ObservableObject` that I can later use as an `EnvironmentObject` throughout the app.

Comment: Thats fine if it's the object that manages the model structs. By the way you can also use @.AppStorage for settings.

Answer (score 0):

One way to initialize `ObservableObject` that depends on environment is to pass the necessary environment from a parent view via a view `init` that itself creates a StateObject using `wrappedValue:` initializer.

###### Disclosure

Following is a link to my article describing the solution in more detail:

[ObservableObject initialisation using Environment](https://medium.com/@pavel-holec/observableobject-initialisation-from-environment-2efa054de06d)

Comment: You **must** disclose your affiliation to any linked sites (here and one of your other answers), or your answers may be flagged as spam.